# In 'call someone here', is 'here' locative or temporal?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

I was looking at the meaning of [call](http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/call), one meaning says

> (transitive) If you call somebody somewhere, you ask or tell them to come there.

One sample usage is

> My boss called me to his office and explained the problem.
>
> In the afternoon she called me to the cafeteria to discuss the issue.

Let's say my colleague calls me and asks me to be at a particular spot at 2 o'clock, So I at 2 go to that place and wait for him to show up. Say my other friend finds me there and asks me what I am doing there. So, can I say

> X(my friend) called me **here** to meet him.

My question is that does **here** convey the message that my friend asked me to be at a particular point, Instead of saying that **he called me at this point say my desk or my house**?

Comment: Yes sure it does. 'coz you're already there.

Comment: The sentence can be like, 'He asked me to meet him here'.

Comment: @VijayaRagavan What do you mean, "because you're already there"? What does that have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: This is just perverse conflation of *call = contact by telephone* and *call = summons to appear*.

Comment: @WendiKidd: OP by saying 'here', he is in the place where his friend asked him to be. So it conveys the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart question! I like it.

The specific wording you've used means *he asked me to be in this particular place*, but if you meant to say *he called me on the phone* you could just change the wording around.

> My friend called me here to meet him.

To *call someone [somewhere]* means *to ask that someone come to a certain place*. And that's what you've said here; your friend *called you here to meet him*. However if we change the wording a bit:

> My friend called me and asked me to meet him here.

Now this is referring to the actual phone call. *My friend called me* means that he picked up the phone and dialed your number. Then you describe what he said to you when he made that call: *he asked me to meet him here*.

So there's no ambiguity in the sentence you posed, because we express these two concepts a bit differently.